# How do I reloadData in a tableView when a UIAlertView button has been pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a list of names in a `UITableView`. The tableView's delegate is a viewController. I use an `IBAction` to call an `UIAlertView` (with a text field) so the user can add another name to the tableView:

```
- (IBAction)addGuest:(UIButton *)sender
{   
    // open a alert with text field, cancel and add button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add New Guest" message:@"Example: John Doe" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}
```

When the user clicks the 'Add' button in the `UIAlertView`, I write the information in the text field to a plist:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Guests.plist"];

        [self.guestList addObject:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]];

        NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:guestList, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nameList", nil]];
        NSString *error = nil;
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
        if (plistData) {
            [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, I'd like to do a reload on the tableView (inside the above method) so the newly added name appears. I've set the `UIAlertView`'s delegate to self.

However, `[self.tableView reloadData]` doesn't work because tableView isn't recognized in this method. I've tried lots of variations, but I can't get anything to work.

How do I do this ?

Thank you!

Comment: tableView isn't recognized?  Please explain.  If the view controller is not a UITableViewController, then you'll need to add the table view property yourself.

Comment: Exactly as danh says. Do you have an IBOutlet for the tableview set in your view controllers header file?

Answer (score 1):

Every view controller has a view.  Is the view of your table view's delegate controller the table view?  If so, try:

```
[((UITableView *) self.view) reloadData]
```

in the implementation of the didDismissWithButtonIndex method.  The above *only* works if the tableView's delegate controller is *also* the delegate for the UIAlertView.  You would accomplish that with: `

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
    <UITableViewDataSource,
      UITableViewDelegate,
      UIAlertViewDelegate> { /* .... */ }  /* ... */ @end
```

or better (but not always possible):

```
@interface SomeViewController : UITableViewController      // <- Now you'll have self.tableView 
    < UIAlertViewDelegate> { /* .... */ } /* ... */ @end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [tableview reloadData] method you should implement the

```
uitableviewdelegate,uitabbleviewdatasource     
reloadData works only if you implement the  following three delegate methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Instead of using  `- (IBAction)addGuest:(UIButton *)`sender you can use the delegate method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

NB:dont forget to set the delegate and datasource to tableview to the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {
```

[tableviewName reloadData];
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Create an outlet for your table view, connect it in inteface builder

**in .h**

```
IBOutlet UITableView *exercisesTable;
```

**in .m class**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {   



    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // your code
        [exercisesTable reloadData];
    }
}
```